# How to fix ClassNotFound Warning in Morphia

Tags: java, json, mongodb, morphia, database

It's some days that I try to resolve the following warning using Morphia for **mongodb** in my servlet project:

```
 Class not found defined in dbObj: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.frametech.pns.configurator.morphomodel.Applications
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.getClass(DefaultCreator.java:126)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:58)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:306)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:87)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:73)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:68)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:323)
    at it.frametech.pns.configurator.database.DatabaseManager.getApplicationByName(DatabaseManager.java:79)
    at it.frametech.pns.configurator.ConfiguratorServlet.doGet(ConfiguratorServlet.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It is called here:

```
public Applications getApplicationByName(String name){
    List<Applications> applicationsList = mDatastore.createQuery(Applications.class).field("name").equal(name).asList();
    if(!applicationsList.isEmpty())
        for(Applications applications : applicationsList)
            return applications;
    return null;
}
```

The Morphia model classes are these:

```
  @Entity
public class Applications extends BaseEntity{


    private String name;    
    private String owner;   
    private String version;

    @Embedded
    List<Resources> resources = new ArrayList<>();

    @Embedded
    List<Activities> activities = new ArrayList<>();

    @Embedded
    List<Components> components = new ArrayList<>();

    public Applications() {
        super();
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public Applications setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
        return this;
    }

    public List<Resources> getResources() {
        return resources;
    }

    public Applications setResources(List<Resources> resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
        return this;
    }

    public Applications addResource(Resources newResource) {
        if (!this.resources.contains(newResource)) {
          this.resources.add(newResource);
        }
        return this;
      }

    public Applications removeResource(Resources newResource) {
        if (this.resources.contains(newResource)) {
          this.resources.remove(newResource);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public List<Activities> getActivities() {
        return activities;
    }

    public Applications setActivities(List<Activities> activities) {
        this.activities = activities;
        return this;
    }

    public Applications addActivity(Activities newActivity) {
        if (!this.activities.contains(newActivity)) {
          this.activities.add(newActivity);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Applications removeActivity(Activities newActivity) {
        if (this.activities.contains(newActivity)) {
          this.activities.remove(newActivity);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public List<Components> getComponents() {
        return components;
    }

    public Applications setComponents(List<Components> components) {
        this.components = components;
        return this;
    }

    public Applications addComponent(Components newComponent) {
        if (!this.components.contains(newComponent)) {
          this.components.add(newComponent);
        }
        return this;
     }

    public Applications removeComponent(Components newComponents) {
        if (this.components.contains(newComponents)) {
          this.components.remove(newComponents);
        }
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        /*
        return  DatabaseModel.ApplicationsModel.DOCUMENT_NAME + " [id=" + id + 
                ", name=" + name + 
                ", telephone=" + telephone + ", email=" +
                   email + ", web=" + web + ", creationDate=" + creationDate + ", lastChange=" +
                   lastChange + ", employees=" + employees + ", bankConnection=" + bankConnection +
                   ", address=" + address + "]";
    */return null;
    }
```

Other embedded classes:

```
@Embedded
public class Resources {
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private String type;

    public Resources() {
        super();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the java version you are using ?

Comment: danilo@danilo-K53SV:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)